# Accessing a function of an anonymous class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in Python and have gone through some help material on __ symbol and my question is based on it.

I have executed the following in a Python 3.7 shell / interpreter:

```
 class __:

...     def strangeClassName():

...             print("Inside a function")

…

 inst = __()
```

which is not problematic at all. However, when I try to access the print statement using the function name(strangeClassName()), I am not able to get it. I mean - not able to see the print's output.

What is happening and how to access the function, as the call **inst.strangeClassName** did not help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must specify the first argument that represents the instance object for all instance methods. The name `self` is only convention and you can name it your way. But following the convention is the good practice.

Looks like this:

```
class __:
    def foo(self):
        print("inside")


inst = __()
inst.foo()
```

Output:

```
inside
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. So, can I consider passing 'self' to every method as a best practice & is a must for instance methods (as against static methods) ?